# Divide String by StringTokenizer and then save to 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, stringtokenizer

Imagine this array.

```
data[0] : 208.92.249.53:80
data[1] : 115.124.65.74:3128
data[2] : 49.213.17.92:8080
```

I want to split data[]. And extract ip and port number.

```
ip[0] : 208.92.249.53
ip[1] : 115.124.65.74
ip[2] : 49.213.17.92
port[0] : 80
port[1] : 3128
port[2] : 8080
```

How can I do that?

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(data[i], ":");
while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
        //??????
}
```

I don't know how can I save to 2 different array. please let me show how to do that... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(data[i], ":");

  while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
     ip[i]=stringTokenizer.nextToken();
     port[i]=stringTokenizer.nextToken();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] ip = new String[data.length];
String[] port = new String[data.length];

for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
   String[] split = data[i].split(":");
   ip[i] = split[0];
   port[i] = split[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer ist deprecated use `array.split()` instead.

```
String[] tmp = data[i].split(":");
ip[i] = tmp[0];
port[i] = tmp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] arrTokens =data[0].split(":");
```

Comment: [You might want to add a link to the method...](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe StringTokenizer is not what you want. You can do this via `split` command

```
String[] ip = new String[data.length];
String[] port = new String[data.length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
   String[] splitted = data[i].split(":");
   ip[i] = splitted[0];
   port[i] = splitted[1];
}
```